# Unit testing a python app that uses the requests library

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, python-requests

I am writing an application that performs REST operations using Kenneth Reitz's [requests library](https://github.com/psf/requests) and I'm struggling to find a nice way to unit test these applications, because requests provides its methods via module-level methods.

What I want is the ability to synthesize the conversation between the two sides; provide a series of request assertions and responses.

Comment: So you need to mock out the REST server?

Comment: why does that make unittest unsuitable? Check how the library does its own unit tests; might offer ideas.

Comment: FWIW, the Requests library does its own tests using live URLs (github.com, the authors own domain, etc.).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It is in fact a little strange that the library has a blank page about end-user unit testing, while targeting user-friendliness and ease of use. There's however an easy-to-use library by Dropbox, unsurprisingly called [`responses`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/responses). Here is its [intro post](http://cra.mr/2014/05/20/mocking-requests-with-responses). It says they've failed to employ [`httpretty`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httpretty/), while stating no reason of the fail, and written a library with similar API.

```
import unittest

import requests
import responses


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

  @responses.activate  
  def testExample(self):
    responses.add(**{
      'method'         : responses.GET,
      'url'            : 'http://example.com/api/123',
      'body'           : '{"error": "reason"}',
      'status'         : 404,
      'content_type'   : 'application/json',
      'adding_headers' : {'X-Foo': 'Bar'}
    })

    response = requests.get('http://example.com/api/123')

    self.assertEqual({'error': 'reason'}, response.json())
    self.assertEqual(404, response.status_code)
```

Comment: Updated URL for the `responses` [**intro post**](http://cra.mr/2014/05/20/mocking-requests-with-responses)

Comment: Interestingly, since this was posted as an answer, David Cramer –who authored this library– moved on and founded Sentry, and [moved the library with him](https://github.com/getsentry/responses/commit/fe1e389dabea0a79cba59b720ef6d91ff40f53cb). This is why on GitHub it’s under the `getsentry` org.

Answer (score 50):

If you use specifically requests try [httmock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httmock/). It's wonderfully simple and elegant:

```
from httmock import urlmatch, HTTMock
import requests

# define matcher:
@urlmatch(netloc=r'(.*\.)?google\.com$')
def google_mock(url, request):
    return 'Feeling lucky, punk?'

# open context to patch
with HTTMock(google_mock):
    # call requests
    r = requests.get('http://google.com/')
print r.content  # 'Feeling lucky, punk?'
```

If you want something more generic (e.g. to mock any library making http calls) go for [httpretty](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httpretty/).

Almost as elegant:

```
import requests
import httpretty

@httpretty.activate
def test_one():
    # define your patch:
    httpretty.register_uri(httpretty.GET, "http://yipit.com/",
                        body="Find the best daily deals")
    # use!
    response = requests.get('http://yipit.com')
    assert response.text == "Find the best daily deals"
```

HTTPretty is far more feature-rich - it offers also mocking status code, streaming responses, rotating responses, dynamic responses (with a callback).

Comment: That httpretty thing is straight from out of this world, thanks!

Answer (score 22):

You could use a mocking library such as [Mocker](http://niemeyer.net/mocker) to intercept the calls to the requests library and return specified results.

As a very simple example, consider this class which uses the requests library:

```
class MyReq(object):
    def doSomething(self):
        r = requests.get('https://api.github.com', auth=('user', 'pass'))
        return r.headers['content-type']
```

Here's a unit test that intercepts the call to `requests.get` and returns a specified result for testing:

```
import unittest
import requests
import myreq

from mocker import Mocker, MockerTestCase

class MyReqTests(MockerTestCase):
    def testSomething(self):
        # Create a mock result for the requests.get call
        result = self.mocker.mock()
        result.headers
        self.mocker.result({'content-type': 'mytest/pass'})

        # Use mocker to intercept the call to requests.get
        myget = self.mocker.replace("requests.get")
        myget('https://api.github.com', auth=('user', 'pass'))
        self.mocker.result(result)

        self.mocker.replay()

        # Now execute my code
        r = myreq.MyReq()
        v = r.doSomething()

        # and verify the results
        self.assertEqual(v, 'mytest/pass')
        self.mocker.verify()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run this unit test I get the following result:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

OK
```

Answer (score 3):

Missing from these answers is [**requests-mock**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-mock).

From their page:

> ```
> >>> import requests
> >>> import requests_mock
> ```
>
> As a context manager:
>
> ```
> >>> with requests_mock.mock() as m:
>
> ...     m.get('http://test.com', text='data')
> ...     requests.get('http://test.com').text
> ...
> 'data'
> ```
>
> Or as a decorator:
>
> ```
> >>> @requests_mock.mock()
> ... def test_func(m):
> ...     m.get('http://test.com', text='data')
> ...     return requests.get('http://test.com').text
> ...
> >>> test_func()
> 'data'
> ```

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of how to make this work with ``pytest``? I tried the exact example you're citing. Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703748/why-does-the-simplest-requests-mock-example-fail-with-pytest

Comment: If I remember correctly, I used the decorator. And I think this also worked with pytest.

Comment: I made it work with decorators, but it appears (on my system) that it's in conflict with some other argument, so I had to pass a kw argument to the Mocker, as mentioned in [docs](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mocker.html#decorator). Not sure if this has to do with pytest, but the error that came up mentioned fixtures. Thanks for getting back to the issue.

Answer (score 2):

using mocker like in srgerg's answer:

```
def replacer(method, endpoint, json_string):
    from mocker import Mocker, ANY, CONTAINS
    mocker = Mocker()
    result = mocker.mock()
    result.json()
    mocker.count(1, None)
    mocker.result(json_string)
    replacement = mocker.replace("requests." + method)
    replacement(CONTAINS(endpoint), params=ANY)
    self.mocker.result(result)
    self.mocker.replay()
```

For the requests library, this would intercept the request by method and endpoint you're hitting and replace the .json() on the response with the json_string passed in.

Answer (score 2):

If you break out your response handler/parser into a separate function, you can work with `requests.Response objects` directly, without needing to mock the client-server interaction.

**Code under test**

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from requests.models import Response

def function_under_test(s3_response: Response):
    doc = minidom.parseString(s3_response.text)

    return (
        s3_response.status_code,
        doc.getElementsByTagName('Code').item(0).firstChild.data,
    )
```

**Test code**

```
import unittest
from io import BytesIO

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_it(self):
        s3_response = Response()
        s3_response.status_code = 404
        s3_response.raw = BytesIO(b"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <Error>
            <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
            <Message>The resource you requested does not exist</Message>
            <Resource>/mybucket/myfoto.jpg</Resource> 
            <RequestId>4442587FB7D0A2F9</RequestId>
            </Error>
        """)

        parsed_response = function_under_test(s3_response)

        self.assertEqual(404, parsed_response[0])
        self.assertEqual("NoSuchKey", parsed_response[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a library for this, if you want to write your test server with Flask: [requests-flask-adaptor](https://github.com/maarten-dp/requests-flask-adapter)

You just have to be careful with the order of imports when monkeypatching.