# python application is not working where i use vpn or @work

Tags: python, python-requests

I wrote a python application and it works fine on my private network.
The application uses requests package and constantly fetching data from Yahoo.finance.

However when my computer is connected to my work network (either through VPN or where i am actually @work),
The application is not working.
Is there a way to make it work?

Asaf

Comment: just to clarify ... when connected to work network , there is no issue visiting yahoo.finance website from the browser ...

Comment: Corporate networks usually route http-traffic through proxies. I strongly assume that this is here also the case.
Have you defined the proxy in the requests module?
Good example from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module

`http_proxy  = "http://10.10.1.10:3128"
https_proxy = "https://10.10.1.11:1080"
ftp_proxy   = "ftp://10.10.1.10:3128"

proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : http_proxy, 
              "https" : https_proxy, 
              "ftp"   : ftp_proxy
            }

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxyDict)`

Comment: Is there a simple way to get proxy http address ? Or i should be get it form IT Admin (which is not possible in my case )

Comment: You can check in your browser proxy settings. Usually there you have either the proxy or an URL to a proxy.pac file which contains the used proxies.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that check.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the firewall settings, or company list over blocked URLs.

It could be that your work has blocked the Yahoo.finance domain or specific applications from having outbound traffic as well.

You might also have success with privilege escalation to admin user which could grant you wider access.

Check if you can ping Yahoo.finance from a terminal or simply open it manually from a few different browsers (Edge, Chrome, Firefox etc.).

Then try to see if you from inside your Python application can fetch any URL with the request module, just to troubleshoot.

Comment: I can access yahoo.finance from the web browser. But application is stuck and do not even open

Comment: You could run a unittest on your application: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077674/7445528 . Remember to modify the url in both the testExample and response variable.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that check.

Comment: It could be any number of things, but probably traces back to the company security setup in some way or form. I would recommend checking the above mentioned things in parallel to pinpoint the issue.