# Unit testing for python function-using post requests and get requests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest.mock

I am trying to test the below function using unit test mocks but i am not able to do it since the return type from request get/post is of type <class 'requests.models.Response'>. please let me know how to mock this and unit test this below function:

```py
def response_check(base_url, headers, schedule_name, response):
    """
    Function to get response from dataform API and check the job status
    """
    run_url = base_url + "/" + response.json()["id"]
    query_response = requests.get(run_url, headers=headers)
    while query_response.json()["status"] == "RUNNING":
        time.sleep(10)
        print("Dataform job running")
        query_response = requests.get(run_url, headers=headers)
        if query_response.json()["status"] in ["FAILED", "CANCELLED", "TIMED_OUT"]:
            raise AirflowException(
                f'Dataform task {schedule_name} has been {response.json()["status"]} for reason {response.json()["runLogUrl"]}'
            )
        print(query_response.json())
    return "Dataform job finished"
```

I need to check for different response status but i am not able to mock the return type of it

Comment: did you try `@patch`?

Comment: I have used patch for request.get but the return type is of class requests.models.Response; so how to mock up the return type of this class.

Comment: Use `side_effect` to provide a list of canned responses; the calls to `requests.get` will use them as they are made.

Answer (score 0):

Please test using http module and the http codes.
For e.g. success is http.HTTPStatus.OK

Not found is http.HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND
Bad input is http.HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST etc.

Comment: I have used responses package which solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559963/unit-testing-a-python-app-that-uses-the-requests-library