# How do I test that a website has a response code of 200 in python unit testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, http-response-codes

So in this unit test file I have tried testing that "WikiVoyage" has a response code of 200 and when I tested that it was fine, it was then when I tried creating a false test it started saying that the response code of 404 was now passing the test, is there any way of testing just the response code of 200

############## python code #############

```
import requests
import json

used_country_list = [
    "Nigeria",
    # "South_West_Nigeria",
    # "Lagos_State",
    # "Lagos_City",
    # "Amuwo_odofin",
    # # California Detail
    # "California",
    # "Southern_California",
    "Los_Angeles",
    # "Los_Angeles/Eastside",
    # "Los_Angeles/Downtown",
    # "Bay_Area",
#     German etc.
    "Germany",
    "Frankfurt",
]

def wikivoyage_extract(used_country_list):
    print(f"[Extractor - WikiVoyage]  pre loop")
    current_dict = {}
    for index, country_name in enumerate(used_country_list):
        url = f"http://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles={country_name}&format=json"
        print(f"[Extractor - WikiVoyage]  url is {url}")
        response = requests.get(url)
        content = json.loads(response.content)
        print(f"[Extractor - WikiVoyage]  response is {response.status_code}")

        pages = content['query']['pages']
        print(f"{index} : {url}")
        for count, key in enumerate(pages):
            if count>0:
                print(country_name, count)
            extract = pages[key]['extract']
        current_dict[country_name] = extract
    return current_dict

wiki_dict = wikivoyage_extract(used_country_list)
```

############## unitest code ##############

```
import unittest

from unit_test import wikivoyage_extract

class ResponseCodeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_is_wikivoyage_200(self):
        self.assertEqual(wikivoyage_extract) == 200

    def test_is_wikivoyage_404(self):
        self.assertFalse(wikivoyage_extract) == 404

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Your `wikivoyage_extract` function does not return a status code.  It returns a dictionary.  So, even without fixing your incorrect use of the assert methods, your design is flawed.  Did you intend to have a separate method do the `requests` call, so you could unit test that method?

Comment: yes I did but I'm unsure about how I create the method for the request call as I'm just trying to test the code that was sent to me to create unit tests for.

Comment: The code is not set up to be unit tested.  If the request gets a 404, the code will crash.  You'll need to determine exactly what they want to be tested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit testing a python app that uses the requests library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559963/unit-testing-a-python-app-that-uses-the-requests-library)

Comment: @TimRoberts this is what they asked me to do in terms of testing I may have interpreted it wrong "Test that we are receiving a 200 status code for each API request"

Comment: That's not a "unit test".  That's asking to add validation to your live code.  Did they tell you what to do if you don't get one?

Comment: Normally we **don't** write unit tests to verify that connecting to a web page gives a `200` status code, because *that web page is not under our control*. Even if we did operate the web page, we don't operate it *using the code that is being tested* - so if we get `404` instead, that *doesn't tell us anything useful about our code* - it only tells use that the website is down.

Answer (score 0):

What they're asking for is SOMETHING like this:

```
import requests
import json

used_country_list = [
    "Nigeria",
    "Los_Angeles",
    "Germany",
    "Frankfurt",
]

def wikivoyage_extract(used_country_list):
    print(f"[Extractor - WikiVoyage]  pre loop")
    current_dict = {}
    for index, country_name in enumerate(used_country_list):
        url = f"http://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles={country_name}&format=json"
        print(f"[Extractor - WikiVoyage]  url is {url}")
        response = requests.get(url)

        content = json.loads(response.content)
        print(f"[Extractor - WikiVoyage]  response is {response.status_code}")
        assert response.status_code == 200

        pages = content['query']['pages']
        print(f"{index} : {url}")
        for count, key in enumerate(pages):
            if count>0:
                print(country_name, count)
            extract = pages[key]['extract']
        current_dict[country_name] = extract
    return current_dict

wiki_dict = wikivoyage_extract(used_country_list)
```

Now, in reality you wouldn't use that exact line, because that will crash the app if the status code is not 200, but you'll need to know what you SHOULD do.  Should you return None?  Should you log the problem?

```
        ...
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print( "*** Bad status code received" )
            return None
```